# What does "Combo" mean on weapons?

Tags: nier-automata

I'm looking through the weapons in my inventory and in the shop and I keep descriptions like this under each weapon:

> Attack: 190 - 210
>
> Combo: Lt 5   Hv 2

What does "Combo" mean in this context?

Comment: Lt = Light Attack , Hv = Heavy Attack. Just experiment between weapon to see the difference. I don't play Nier but i know that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After experimenting with my own weapons, I can confirm that these represent how many moves are in a Light or Heavy combo with that weapon.

That is, if you have a weapon as your Primary with Lt 3 Hv 2, you will do a 3-hit combo with your Light attack button. If you have this weapon as your Secondary (Heavy) weapon, you will do a 2-hit combo with your Heavy attack button.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about how the Combo number relates to Attack? Does it multiply damage? Is it better to have Attack 100 with Combo 4 (400?) or Attack 250 with Combo 2 (500?)

Comment: @neokio it's just hits in a combo. From experience, the damage dealt with each hit will be within the range given by the damage numbers in the weapon's attributes. The combo number just tells you how many hits are in a combo. Doesn't deal with damage output, per se. 4 x 100 vs 2 x 250 probably means the 250 is slower since upgraded weapons only grow in combo number, so it'd have to be a different class of weapon. Does this answer your question(s)?

Comment: I think its a bit more complicated, at least for 2B and A2, since for them you assign a weapon in the light slot and another in the heavy slot.  So you could do a 5 hit combo if you have Light weapon with 3 hits and in the heavy slot that weapon can do 2 heavy hits.

Comment: @Andy what? No, a weapon has a light and heavy combo stat. The light stat applies when you have that weapon in the primary slot. The heavy stat applies only to 2B and A2, who are the only two who can *have* a heavy weapon. The heavy combo stat applies to the weapon in the secondary position. The combo number doesn't have any effect on the *other* weapon. The numbers are only for *that* weapon. So yeah, you could have 3 + 2, but I think that's actually two separate combos, since the 3 would be a full combo (which ends).

Comment: @Vemonus I'm not sure the combo ends if you press light, light, light, heavy, heavy.  Try it on a tough enemy like the bunny.  You should see his life bar grow red with each hit, which indicates the combo damage.  After the combo ends the red portion disappears.

Comment: @Andy the red just indicates that you've been dealing damage without letting up. You could hold down the gun and it would never stop being red. That's not combo damage. If you have a Light 3 weapon and you do 3 light attacks, that is an entire combo. Doing heavy attacks afterwards is a separate combo. Doing a light > heavy or a heavy > light in the same combo will do a different move that indicates it's part of a combo. Like spear light > greatsword heavy will cause 2B/A2 to kick the spear and swing around the spear that's lodged in the ground. But that's only if you do it in one combo.

Comment: @Vemonus Well what is a combo except a number of hits within a certain time frame?  I've done the swing around the spear thing, as a combo ender after doing the light attacks.  There's this thread that talks about combos: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75159795  I'd be very surprised if a Japanese game with light and heavy attacks DIDN'T let you include both in a single combo.

Comment: @Andy you're misunderstanding me. A combo typically entails a finisher. The 3 hit light combo weapon will have a combo finisher as its third attack. As in, that finishes the "combo". If you test it, you'll notice that the three attacks you do are unique but repeat every time you do three attacks. Each one is a combo. Similarly, a 2 heavy combo weapon will do that every 2 hits with heavy attacks. You can combine them, but you can never do more than the number of either light/heavy hits in a row without finishing the combo.

Comment: You *can* combine light and heavy attacks in a combo, but the number on the weapon does not have anything to do with that. Combining the two pretty much acts as a combo finisher. The number refers to the maximum number of hits in a row you can pull off with that type of attack.

Comment: @Vemonus Ah, I think I get what you're saying. So a 3 light 2 heavy you could only do two light then two heavy and have the finisher, as 3 light would end a combo, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Andy yeah, I think. Though, the light > heavy may just be a combo finisher. The numbers don't really mean anything aside from how many hits will be in a combo if you *just* use that type of attack.